# Array splitting and extracting

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm attempting to go through each character in a cell to determine whether or not a word is underlined and italicized but so far the loop runs and freezes. How can I copy and move the word that is italicized and underlined? This is what I have so far. I asked a new question because I wasn't clear enough in this one. It can be accessed at [Array split and extract vba excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750171/array-split-and-extract-vba-excel?noredirect=1#comment64874638_38750171) .

```
For Each j In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C105")
        v = Trim(j.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            v = Replace(v, vbLf, " ")

            Do While InStr(v, "  ") > 0
                v = Replace(v, "  ", " ")
            Loop

            arr = Split(v, " ")

            For Z = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            e = arr(Z)

                For i = 1 To Len(v)
                    If j.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True And j.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = True Then
                        j.Value.Copy


                    End If
                Next i
            Next Z
        End If
   Next j​
```

Comment: You'll need to get the last char of italics etc, so you'll need to continue your loop I believe, then you can use MID  Sorry, ignore that, you're splitting by space, you'll need to paste the split values into a worksheet to do what you are trying.  You could use FIND or SEARCH on the cell you've split for the first position of each word, and check that.  So split A1, then loop the array, getting the position of the word in A1, then check the first char of that.

Comment: I see a few things logically wrong with your approach, but can you give more detail on what you're trying to accomplish? Where do you want to *move* the italicized text?

Comment: @David Zemens There are multiple words in the cell and im moving the italicized and underlined words to a new sheet.

Comment: moving words that are italicized *and* underlined, or moving words that are italicized *or* underlined?

Comment: words that are both italicized and underlined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code will `Debug.Print` all the words that are underlined and formatted italic in any of the given cells:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Range
Dim StartPoint As Long
Dim InItalicUnderlinedWord As Boolean

For Each j In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C1:C105")
    If Len(j.Value2) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(j.Value2)
            If j.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic And j.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline Then
                If InItalicUnderlinedWord = False Then
                    StartPoint = i
                    InItalicUnderlinedWord = True
                End If
            Else
                If InItalicUnderlinedWord = True Then
                    Debug.Print Mid(j.Value2, StartPoint, i - StartPoint)
                    InItalicUnderlinedWord = False
                End If
            End If
            If InItalicUnderlinedWord = True And i = Len(j.Value2) Then
                Debug.Print Mid(j.Value2, StartPoint, i - StartPoint + 1)
                InItalicUnderlinedWord = False
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

`Debug.Print` will output the `italic` and `underlined` word into the immediate window of the VBE. If you want these words anywhere else then you'll have to adjust the code in two (!) places:

1. Once in the section which starts with `InItalicUnderlinedWord` for any find anywhere within a cell and
2. in the section which starts with `If InItalicUnderlinedWord = True And i = Len(j.Value2) Then` for any occurrences where the **last** character in a cell is also `underlined` and `italic`.

Let me know if you have any questions or problems.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having an error come up "Unable to get the characters property of the range class". Do you know what that means?

Comment: Just a wild guess: the cell is protected and / or the sheet is protected (or the file as a whole). If that's not the case then you might want to share with us the content of the cell(s) which give(s) you problem(s).

Comment: It actually seems to be running without errors now but how can I change the lines you suggested to move the words to a new sheet?

Comment: Depends where you want them to be posted. For example: if you want them on `Worksheet(1)` in column `A` to be added then use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2` instead of `Debug.Print` in both cases. So, for example instead of `Debug.Print Mid(j.Value2, StartPoint, i - StartPoint)` just use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = Mid(j.Value2, StartPoint, i - StartPoint)`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this, only does 1 cell, so you'll need to add it to your loop

```
Sub test()

Dim r As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim f As Integer

Set r = Range("h2")
v = Split(r.Value, Chr(32))

For i = 0 To UBound(v) - 1

    f = InStr(1, r, v(i))     ' equiv Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(v(i), r)

    If r.Characters(f, 1).Font.Italic Then
        Debug.Print v(i) & " is italic"
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler implementation involves copying the entire cell values first, and then manipulating the copied range. Call this in a loop, and provide it the two arguments: `rngToCopy` = the cell being copied and `rngToPaste` the destination cell (qualified to specific workbook/worksheet):

```
For each cl in Range("C1:C105")
    Call CopyItalicUnderlined(cl, __Some Place Else__)
Next
```

Here's the procedure

```
Sub CopyItalicUnderlined(rngToCopy, rngToPaste)

rngToCopy.Copy rngToPaste

Dim i
For i = Len(rngToCopy.Value2) To 1 Step -1
    With rngToPaste.Characters(i, 1)
        If Not .Font.Italic And Not .Font.Underline Then
            .Text = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: You're saying that I should put this into a loop? I'm not exactly how you mean. @DavidZemens

Comment: Call the procedure in a loop, as I have done in the example. The first snippet is `For Each cl in ...`. That's the loop which calls the `CopyItalicUnderlined` procedure. You'll of course need to add the new procedure to the VBProject.

Comment: So in the call (cl, _ some place else _) do I just place the location of where to paste?

Comment: yes, `_some_place_else_` should be modified to a valid range destination.

Comment: It runs but stops after 2 cells and it doesn't split each instance into a new cell. It seems to just copy a cell with an underline in one of the words. Do you think splitting the cells and then going by character using your code would work?

Comment: It certainly doesn't stop after 2 cells, unless you've defined a range of only 2 cells. It could be modified to split the results, but that was not a requirement of the original problem statement, please understand that I'm not really inclined to entertain myriad follow-up questions. If you're attempting to use *this* code, but modify it, you should probably ask a *new question* with specific changes/details, that way you expose it to the whole SO community, rather than *just me*.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My apologies for drawing this questions out.

Comment: It's no problem, but that you've already got an "Accepted" answer which presumably works. If that's not the case, then you should un-accept that one, and revise your question with your current problem/code. Cheers & good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750171/array-split-and-extract-vba-excel?noredirect=1#comment64874638_38750171